# Searchview with listview

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to implement Search view in my program but somehow I am unable to get the searched value displayed in the listview even though in Log cat I can see the search result. Here is my code

Adapter class:

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable  {
private ArrayList<Song> songs;
private LayoutInflater songInf;
// private ArrayList<Glossary> glossariesList;
/** This is mainly for listview search **/
private ArrayList<Song> glossariesListForSearch;
private AlphabetIndexer mIndexer;
    private Context mContext;


public SongAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Song> songs)
{       super();
    this.mContext = context;
    this.glossariesListForSearch = songs;
    this.songs=songs;
}

public static abstract class Row {
}

public static final class Section extends Row {
    public final String text;

    public Section(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

public static final class Item extends Row {
    public final String text;

    public Item(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

private List<Row> rows;

public void setRows(List<Row> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    // return songs.size();
    return rows.size(); //this might b the issue
}

@Override
public Row getItem(int position) {
    return rows.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // return 0;
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (getItem(position) instanceof Section) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;

    if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) { // Item
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.song, parent,
                    false);
        }
        final int pos = position;

        Item item = (Item) getItem(position);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_song_title);
        textView.setText(item.text);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"onClick");
                ((MainActivity)mContext).songPicked(pos);
            }
        });
    } else { // Section
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_section,
                    parent, false);
        }

        Section section = (Section) getItem(position);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(section.text.toUpperCase(Locale.US));
    }
    view.setTag(position);
    return view;

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myFilter;
}

Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        songs = (ArrayList<Song>) results.values;
        if (results.count > 0) {
            Log.i("Filtering", "Results count>0" ); 
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<Song> tempGlossaryList = new ArrayList<Song>();

        if (constraint != null && glossariesListForSearch != null) {
            int length = glossariesListForSearch.size();
            Log.i("Filtering", "glossaries size" + length);
            int i = 0;
            while (i < length) {
                Song item = glossariesListForSearch.get(i);
                // Real filtering:
                if (item.getTitle().toLowerCase()
                        .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    tempGlossaryList.add(item);
                }
                i++;
            }

            filterResults.values = tempGlossaryList;
            filterResults.count = tempGlossaryList.size();
            Log.i("Filtering", "Filter result count size"
                    + filterResults.count);
        }
        return filterResults;
    }
};
```

}

Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
{
     @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    setupSearchView(searchItem);
    return true;
}
  private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {

  mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
  }

 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
 // mStatusView.setText("Query = " + newText);
  Log.i("Action Search Query", newText);
  songAdt.getFilter().filter(newText);
 Log.i("mAdapter", ""+newText);
  return true;
}

 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
  //mStatusView.setText("Query = " + query + " : submitted");
Log.i("Action Search Query", query);
  return false;
  }

public boolean onClose() {
    // mStatusView.setText("Closed!");
    Log.i("Action Search Query", "^%^%^%^%^");
    return false;
}

protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you might have to set the adpater again, fresh with the new records may be.. cud u try that though ?

Comment: Tried setting the adapter again but that doesnt help.

Comment: NotifyDataSetChanged doesnt change anything :(

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille can you help me out?

Comment: i wud suggest u look at [1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/), [2](https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308) ,[3](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2014/02/add-searching-in-list-view.html).. i guess the second link would be much useful ..